# How is a sessionID generated?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

When running a java web application with the servlet api (like JSF or JSP pages), somewhere along the line a 'unique' SessionID is generated to identify the user's session.

I'm wondering how these sessionID's are generated. Do they include the IP of the client? A timestamp? Random numbers?

Secondly, I'm wondering where this generation happens? Is this dependent on the server that runs the application?

Comment: So this looks like there is no out-of-the-box protection against session replay. We tested it, and you can indeed just tamper with your JSESSIONID cookie value to hijack another user's session. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is container specific. Tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html#Manager

Comment: Turns out that for Tomcat, their recently released Tomcat 7.0.59 has an extendable SessionIDGenerator http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html

Answer (score 4):

A `java.security.MessageDigest` algorithm is normally used.

Usually the generated ID is just a set of random numbers, up until the required length, but it varies according to the algorithms used in the various servlet containers.

In Tomcat6, for example, have a look at:

```
ManagerBase.sessionIdLength
```

and

```
ManagerBase.createSession() //which calls generateSessionId()
```

See http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/catalina/session/ManagerBase.java.html

Answer (score 3):

[http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getId()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getId%28%29)

"The identifier is assigned by the servlet container and is implementation dependent."

The jsessionid is generated whenever a new session is created.

Answer (score -1):

> Here is complete code of you Question
>
> Create login.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="US-ASCII">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <h1>Please login to continue</h1>
</head>
<body>

<form action="LoginServlet" method="post">

    User Name: <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

> Create LoginServlet

```
package com.self.sessionid;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.CookieStore;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final String username = "admin";
    private final String password = "password";
    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("pwd");
        System.out.println("%%%%%");
        
        if(this.username.equals(username) && this.password.equals(password)) {
            HttpSession oldSession = request.getSession(false);
            if(oldSession != null) {
                oldSession.invalidate();
            }
            HttpSession newSession = request.getSession(true);
            newSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(1*60);
            Cookie message = new Cookie("message", "welcome");
            response.addCookie(message);
            
            String messag = null;
            String sessionID = null;
            Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
            if(cookies != null){
                for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
                    if(cookie.getName().equals("message")) messag = cookie.getValue();
                    if(cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID")) sessionID = cookie.getValue();
            }
            }
            
            
            
            System.out.println("message : " + messag);
            System.out.println("Session Id : " + sessionID);
            
            
            /* response.sendRedirect("/loginSuccess.jsp"); */
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/loginSuccess.jsp");
            rd.include(request, response);
        } else {
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<font color=red>Either username or password is wrong.</font>");
            rd.include(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

> Create loginSuccess.jsp file in WebComponent

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%-- <%
    String message = null;
    String sessionID = null;
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if(cookies != null){
        for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
            if(cookie.getName().equals("message")) message = cookie.getValue();
            if(cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID")) sessionID = cookie.getValue();
        }
    }
%> --%>
    <h3>Login Success</h3>
    <%-- <h4><%=message%></h4>
    <h4>Session ID = <%=sessionID %></h4>
 --%>   <br><br>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <form action="LogoutServlet" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" >
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> Create LogoutServlet

```
package com.self.sessionid;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LogoutServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/LogoutServlet")
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if(session != null){
            session.invalidate();
        }
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp");
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this following code:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String sessionid = session.getId();
sessionid = sessionid.substring((sessionid.length() - 23), sessionid.length());
```